# Console Application VB how to center screen

Tags: vb.net

how can make my app open in the center of the screen? I know how to work with a Form application, but I don't know how to work with a console, because it doesn't work the same way.

```
       Console.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2,
                          (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2)

 Console.SetWindowPosition(0, 0)
```

Comment: See [Console.SetWindowPosition -> centered (each and every time)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888913/719186)

Comment: is for C ++ C # and I code in VB.

Comment: It's not c++.  c# and vb.net are very similar.  It should be enough to help you.  There are c# -> vb.net conversion tools.

Comment: The .Net calls do the work here and they should be the same on both languages (C# and VB.net).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.SetWindowPosition -> centered (each and every time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888824/console-setwindowposition-centered-each-and-every-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Shared Sub CenterConsole()
    Dim hWin As IntPtr = GetConsoleWindow()
    Dim rc As RECT
    GetWindowRect(hWin, rc)
    Dim scr As Screen = Screen.FromPoint(New Point(rc.left, rc.top))
    Dim x As Integer = scr.WorkingArea.Left + (scr.WorkingArea.Width - (rc.right - rc.left)) / 2
    Dim y As Integer = scr.WorkingArea.Top + (scr.WorkingArea.Height - (rc.bottom - rc.top)) / 2
    MoveWindow(hWin, x, y, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, False)
End Sub

Private Structure RECT
    Public left, top, right, bottom As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <Out> ByRef rc As RECT) As Boolean
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function MoveWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal w As Integer, ByVal h As Integer, ByVal repaint As Boolean) As Boolean
```

And when you want to center the console window just call the CenterConsole sub like this:

```
CenterConsole()
```

Comment: Direct conversion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888913/1797425?

Answer (score 0):

Same as above with fixes to remove errors and add a second center to show how to move it to a 2nd monitor.

Also, I want to say thanks for the help in getting this figured out. I had not seen the GetConsoleWindow before this.

```
Public Shared Sub CenterConsole()
    Dim hWin As IntPtr = GetConsoleWindow()
    Dim rc As RECT
    GetWindowRect(hWin, rc)
    Dim scr As Screen = Screen.FromPoint(New Point(rc.left, rc.top))
    Dim x As Integer = scr.WorkingArea.Left + (scr.WorkingArea.Width - (rc.right - rc.left)) / 2
    Dim y As Integer = scr.WorkingArea.Top + (scr.WorkingArea.Height - (rc.bottom - rc.top)) / 2
    MoveWindow(hWin, x, y, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, False)
End Sub



Public Shared Sub CenterConsoleRightMonitor()
    Dim hWin As IntPtr = GetConsoleWindow()
    Dim rc As RECT
    GetWindowRect(hWin, rc)
    Dim scr As Screen = Screen.AllScreens(1)
    Dim x As Integer = scr.WorkingArea.Left + (scr.WorkingArea.Width - (rc.right - rc.left)) / 2
    Dim y As Integer = scr.WorkingArea.Top + (scr.WorkingArea.Height - (rc.bottom - rc.top)) / 2
    MoveWindow(hWin, x, y, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, False)
End Sub

' Screen.AllScreens(0).Bounds.Width + Screen.AllScreens(1).Bounds.Width 


Private Structure RECT
    Public left, top, right, bottom As Integer
End Structure

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr

End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <Out> ByRef rc As RECT) As Boolean

End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function MoveWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal w As Integer, ByVal h As Integer, ByVal repaint As Boolean) As Boolean

End Function
```

Comment: You could have fixed the `/ 2` giving an error for the conversion from Double to Integer by changing it to integer division: `\ 2`, or explicitly convert the expressions to an Integer ;)